# Obtaining upload progress data using XMLHttpRequest in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, upload, xmlhttprequest, progress

I am trying to show a progress report for a file upload. The following function works correctly in Chrome:

```
function loading() {     
  var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if (XHR.upload) { 
    XHR.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
      var bar = document.getElementById('bar');
      var howfar = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
      bar.value = howfar;
    }, false);
  }   
  XHR.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (XHR.readyState==4 && XHR.status==200) {
       document.getElementById('formdiv').innerHTML=XHR.responseText;
    }
  }  
  var form = document.getElementById('updoc');
  var formdata = new FormData(form);
  XHR.open('post', 'progress.php', true)
  XHR.send(formdata);
}
```

However, it only works in Firefox when the following code is included:

```
XHR.addEventListener('loadstart', function() {
  alert('Loading: please wait');
});
```

In that case The progress is shown unless and until OK is clicked in the javascript alert box.
The upload itself is always successful.
Is there a known issue with Firefox in this respect? I am using Firefox 25.0 on Linux, but the same thing happens with Firefox on Windows.
Many answers to questions about this topic on Stack Overflow refer the questioner to jQuery solutions, and I am aware that other approaches are possible, but as the code works correctly in Chrome, and follows the examples shown on the Mozilla Development site, I would welcome  suggestions relevant to this particular case.

Comment: Are you still having this problem? If you still need a solution (which is unlikely...) you can probably do something like `XHR.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { XHR.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) { ... } })`. I think it's likely loadstart is firing immediately, thus delaying execution of the progress event listener attachment. That snippet should have the same effect, but avoid the alert. A simple setTimeout() might also work. Haven't you tried that?